# "Could not locate device support files" with Xcode version 11.3.1 and iOS 13.5.1

Tags: iphone, ios, mojave, xcode

I have the latest version of Xcode (11.3.1) for Mojave installed, but it seems that it doesn't support iOS version 13.5.1. I cannot download later versions as the latest version of Mojave is 10.14.6, and Xcode 11.5+ cannot be downloaded here.

Is the only possible solution downgrading my iPhone back to iOS 13.3? If so, how do you do that?

Edit: It seems like Apple no longer allows downgrading to lower iOS versions, which is a hot load of [expletives], and so the only solution to this problem if you have it is to upgrade to Catalina, unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to Catalina?

Comment: I have not. Is this the only other solution?

Comment: I don't know if its the only solution just that it's possibly a solution.

Comment: @jmh yeah just seems kinda inconvenient as i'm using a friend's mac. i don't want to screw anything up.

Comment: understood!  I don't blame you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[This Stack Overflow question answers this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61013626/how-to-run-xcode-11-4-on-macos-mojave-10-14-6)** You need to copy and paste over the SDK for the iOS version that your phone runs on into this file location: `<where ever xcode is located on your machine>/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`.

After downloading the appropriate file, you can go to Terminal and paste this:

```
unzip /Users/yourname/Downloads/13.5.zip
cp ~/Users/yourname/Downloads/13.5 ~/Users/yourname/location/of/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.plaform/DeviceSupport
```

Here's the [link](https://github.com/haikieu/xcode-developer-disk-image-all-platforms/blob/master/DiskImages/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/13.5.zip) to the SDK for iOS version 13.5 (includes 13.5.1) that you need to paste over.

You can also update to Catalina to get a later version of Xcode, but I don't recommend it if this is the only thing you're doing it for.

Apple no longer allows you to downgrade your iOS version, so that option is now, sadly, null.

**Edit**: I just wanted to make it clear that this approach works for all versions of iOS, not just 13.5. Just download the your system version's corresponding file and paste it into the location mentioned before. Make sure to unzip the file before pasting it though.